# Simple proof of Krein-Smulian

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question concerning a simple and short proof of Krein-Shmulian, the proof can be found here [https://people.math.ethz.ch/~jteichma/slides_ftap.pdf](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Ejteichma/slides_ftap.pdf) on page 35/36. Here the proof:

Let $X$ be a Banach space. The Krein-Smulian theorem tells that a convex subset $C\subset X^∗$ is weak-∗-closed if and only if its intersections with balls in $X^∗$ are weak-∗-closed.

We can conclude this theorem from a separation theorem (see Conways’ book on functional analysis): assume that for a convex set $C \subset X^*$ all its intersections with balls in $X^*$ are weak-∗-closed, and assume that the intersection of $C$ with the unit ball (centered at $0$) is empty, then there is $x \in X$ such that $(x,x∗)\geq 1$ for all $x^* \in C$.

From this we can conclude immediately:  let $x^* \in X^*$ be in the weak-∗=closure of $C$ but not in $C$, then – due to the fact that $C$ is norm closed (prove it!)  – there is a ball of radius $r$ around $x^∗$ which does not intersect $C$.  Whence $r^{−1}(C−x^*)$ does not intersect the unit ball centered at $0$. By the previous separation statement this however means that $x^*$ cannot lie in the weak-∗-closure of $C$.

---

While the statements on the first page are clear to me, I have some problems with page 36:

First, it is a well known fact that if $S \subset X$ and convex ($X$ being a vector space carrying a norm) is a weak closed convex set if and only if $S$ is also strongly closed.

But how one get's that that if $C$ is a convex set where its intersection with balls in $X^*$ are weak*-closed, then $C$ is norm closed ?

And further, having this fact, why we can find a ball of radius $r$ around $x^*$ (where $x^*$ is in the weak*-closure but not in $C$) which does not intersect $C$ ? And why this finally implies the statement ?

Comment: Actually this is trivial: in any normed space (more generally, in  any $A_1$ topological space) a set is (topologically) closed iff it is sequentially closed. Also, a converging sequence in any normed space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ (more generally, in any TVS) is always bounded. So any $A\subset X$ is norm-closed iff $A\cap \overline {B(0,r)}$ is closed for any $r>0$.

Comment: In fact the quoted separation theorem is just a slightly different rewording of the Krein-Shmulyan theorem, and the linked proof can’t be called a proof of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello and welcome to MSE!

Let's denote by $B(\cdot,r)$ the ball centered at $\cdot$ of radius $r>0$.

1. Let $X$ be a normed space, $C\subset X^*$ a convex set so that $C\cap B(f,r)$ is weak-star closed for all $f\in X^*$ and all $r>0$. Then $C$ is norm-closed.

Proof: Let $f\in\overline{C}$, the norm-closure and find a sequence $(f_n)\subset C$ so that $f_n\to f$ in norm. Note that $\{\|f_n-f\|\}$ is bounded (since it converges to 0) so $(f_n)\subset B(f,r)$ for some $r>0$. Therefore $(f_n)\subset C\cap B(f,r)$ and $f_n\to f$ in norm, we also have that $f_n\to f$ weak-star, since the norm topology is stronger than the weak-star topology. But since $C\cap B(f,r)$ is weak-star closed by assumption, we have that $f\in C\cap B(f,r)$, so $f\in C$.

Note that we didn't really use convexity for this part.

2. In the same setting as above, let $f\in\overline{C}^{wk^*}\setminus C$. Since $C$ is norm-closed and $f\not\in C$, we have that $f$ does not belong to the norm closure of $C$ (because $C=\overline{C}^{\|\cdot\|}$!), i.e. there exists $r>0$ such that $B(f,r)\cap C=\emptyset$.

As the slides suggest, this means that $\frac{1}{r}(C-f)$ does not intersect the closed unit ball. The separation theorem displayed in the first part (which is essentially Hahn-Banach) shows that there exists a point $x\in X$ so that $g(x)\geq1$ for all $g\in\frac{1}{r}(C-f)$.

Take a net $\{c_i\}_{i\in I}\subset C$ converging to $f$ weak-star. Then $\frac{1}{r}(c_i-f)\in\frac{1}{r}(C-f)$, so $\frac{1}{r}(c_i-f)(x)\geq1$, so $c_i(x)-f(x)\geq r$ and this is true for all $i\in I$. Taking limits as $i\in I$, since $c_i\to f$ weak-star, hence $c_i(x)\to f(x)$, this shows that $0\geq r$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation which made the statement crystal clear! So if I am correct, the contradiction implies that $C$ is already weak-*-closed. I guess I overlooked something, but where did we use that $X$ is complete ?

Comment: @LindaWeder Yes, you are correct about the contradiction. About the completeness, that's an interesting question. J.B. Conway's book phrases this question for the reader in the Krein-Smulian section (p. 160). I can only say that the completeness assumption is used in the part where it says "if $C\cap B(0,1)=\emptyset$, then there exists $x\in X$ such that $(x,x^*)\geq1$ for all $x\in C$". To get into more details, you need to unwind the proof of this; it can be found on Conway's book as I said, or in these cute lecture notes: https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/func-an-2007-2008/bs-5.pdf

Comment: @LindaWeder If you go through the proof carefully, you will identify the use of completeness. Besides that part, it is not used anywhere else (e.g. it is not used anywhere in my answer).

Comment: Very nice. Just a small comment, it's not necessary to use all balls; just balls centered at the origin are enough.